# Determine subset using recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, set, subset, infinite-loop

I am trying to write a function `subset` which takes two lists and determines whether the elements of the first appear in the second.

The code compiles to the GHCi but does not run (i.e. becomes stuck) when a function like the following is entered:

```
subset [1,2] [1,2]
```

This is my code:

```
subset :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
subset [] ys = True
subset (x:xs) ys
 | elem x ys = subset (x:xs) ys
 | otherwise =  False
```

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps of interest: you don't need to explicitly branch on `elem x ys` like that. You can `subset (x:xs) ys = elem x ys && subset {- ... see answers below ... -} ys` and laziness will make sure the recursive call only happens when it needs to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
subset (x:xs) ys
 | elem x ys = subset (x:xs) ys
                   -- ^^^^^^ --
```

Note that the recursive call above does not change the arguments! This will lead to infinite recursion. You want to remove `x` before making the recursive call.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look closely at a fragment of your code:

```
subset (x:xs) ys
 | elem x ys = subset (x:xs) ys
```

In case `elem x ys` holds, which is entirely plausible, you have

```
subset (x:xs) ys = subset (x:xs) ys
```

which performs no reduction in any of its arguments, and just repeats the same call anew.

Hence, infinite loop.

When working with Boolean values, it is customary to use logical connectives, which often leads to more concise and clear definitions:

```
subset (x:xs) ys = elem x ys && subset ..... .....
```

is all you need there, because the truth table of `(&&)` is

```
    True  && x  =  x
    False && _  =  False
```

i.e. when the first argument is false, the second argument's value is not even inspected.

Answer (score 4):

Explicit recursion isn't required; you can use `all` to verify that `` (`elem` ys) `` is true for every value in `xs`:

```
subset xs ys = all (`elem` ys) xs
```